# Invalid 'accounts' entry for network 'sepolia': expected an array of accounts of the string 'remote', but got the string '0x......'

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am following the Blockchain Council Certification for Web 3 Game Development and I am running into issues when compiling.

I have tried everything I can find (which is very little unfortunately) on the specific error I am getting.  I have gone through each and every potential solution for the error and I cannot get it to compile properly.  I am a novice developer so I am sure I have done/am doing something fundamentally wrong.

See code below

Using hardhat, npm;

/////////////////////////////////////////////

.ENV FILE (in same 'Contracts' directory as hardhat.config.js file)

```
URL = 'https://sepolia.infura...."
KEY = '0xexportedprivatekeyfrommetamask'
```

hardhat.config.js file

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("dotenv").config();


const {URL, KEY} = process.env;

import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig 
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.18",
  defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
  networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      sepolia : {
        url: URL,
        accounts: KEY,
      },
  },
};
```

If it is on the community site anywhere as a potential solution, I have likely tried it.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong at this point and just want to get this working.  Thank you.